# Changing view frame size

Tags: macos, swift

Working on https://github.com/madebybright/Nimble/

Trying to change the view frame size when the query function is run, but I keep getting

> This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.

when the query function runs.

When assigning the size in `viewDidLoad` everything works fine, but in `query` (https://github.com/madebybright/Nimble/blob/unstable/Nimble/MenuViewController.swift#L43) the error is thrown.

Any idea why?

Comment: Use dispatch_async because you can't modify view in  background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It's because

> This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread.

:)

To be more specific, you ***must*** do all UI-related work on the main thread. You can use [`dispatch_async`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/) to enqueue a task (such as your frame-size adjustment) on the main thread.

Comment: That eliminates the error but doesn't actually change the size of the frame.